# WordPress Child Theme for specific roles

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, admin, roles

I'd like to restrict a child theme to only being visible to me, the admin, for development purposes. Then I can make changes, upload and view them live and on the site without other people seeing those unfinished changes. Once I'm done, I take the affected files and move them to the Parent Theme's folder to make the changes visible to everyone.

Is this possible with some kind of script through functions.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably want to create a development environment on a subdomain, but if you are restricted by this, you will want to enqueue the style only when you are logged in.

In style.css (change twenty fourteen to match your current theme)

```
/*
Theme Name:   Twenty Fourteen Child
Theme URI:    http://example.com/twenty-fourteen-child/
Template:     twentyfourteen
*/

@import url("../twentyfourteen/style.css");
```

In header.php

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    if ( $user_id = YOUR_USER_ID ) {
        wp_register_style('YOUR_STYLE', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'PATH.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('YOUR_STYLE');
    }
}
```

This should be the general idea of what you want to do. Comment if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The problem with creating a development environment on a subdomain (I've already tried) is that I also have a phpBB forum on my site which I pull user data from to integrate it with the WordPress site. This gets very clunky when cloning the WordPress setup to a different folder on the server, however yes, it's possible. I thought maybe I'd try this instead :)

Is there a way to have the header.php be identical to the one in the parent theme though? Perhaps insert a secondary check to see whether it's a child theme or a parent theme?

Comment: If you include the code I gave you in your current header, that should do the trick because a child theme will pull from your parent files if a child version of it does not exist.

Comment: I'd like to include more than just another style.css, also other files that I place in the child theme folder, such as sidebar.php